# Repeating surround with "." command in VIM

Tags: vim, surround

Did anybody get [surround.vim](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1697) to work with [repeat.vim](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2136)?

This should enable you to repeat any command provided by the surround plugin with the "." command.

I think surround.vim should already have builtin support for the repeat plugin, so it should work out of the box but I can't get it to work.

Comment: I was wondering the same thing. For example, when building a list it would be sweet to do a `yss<li>`, go to the next line and hit `.` without having to re-type li.

Comment: It looks like [surround.vim](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1697) and [visualrepeat.vim](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3848) don't work together. This is what I am looking for.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I just put surround.vim and repeat.vim in my .vim/plugins folder and tried it out. For me, it works like described.

May you try the repeat command on a function that is *not* supported. In the docs of surround.vim it says

```
 The "." command will work with ds, cs, and yss if you install repeat.vim
```

It does not say that *all* commands work with repeat.vim. E.g. the visual mode stuff (select multiple lines and surround them) does not work with repeat.vim

Comment: You should put `repeat.vim` to `autoload/` directory, not to `plugin/`.

Answer (score 6):

You were right. It seems to only work on ds, cs and yss.

It also works, partially, on `yse`, `ysiw`, `ysaw`, `ys2w`. When you repeat a ysiw command it will stop at a prompt waiting for you to input a type of surrounding (i.e. b, B, r, ", t...).

Still no visual commands though. I hope there'll be future versions with added support for the rest of the commands.

Thanks for the answer.