# How do I surround two words with <code> tag in vim, such that I can repeat the operation with a dot operator?

Tags: vim, surround

I'm working with the vim-surround plugin and this HTML (where the * is my cursor):

```
<li class="sample" style="border-color: #005462;">*#005462</li>
```

I'd like to surround the #005462 with `<code>` so it looks like this, `<code>#005462</code>`. I can do this with visual mode but would like to do something I can repeat with the dot operator. Any advice?

Comment: I usually use macros for that sort of thing

Answer (score 9):

You want [repeat.vim](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2136) which adds `.` support to several other plugins, including surround.

Comment: surround.vim and repeat.vim in tandem is definitely the best general-purpose solution to this problem.

Comment: Since he has to use visual mode to select the text, repeat.vim unfortunately won't help in this specific case. See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5794182/how-do-i-surround-two-words-with-code-tag-in-vim-such-that-i-can-repeat-the-op/5795807#5795807) for the rest of the details.

Answer (score 7):

From normal mode try to record a macro. Then:

```
qai<code><esc>ea</code><esc>q
```

1. This command say start recording (q) in a.
2. Start insertion mode (i).
3. Type <code>.
4. Return to normal mode (<esc>).
5. Move to the end of the word (e).
6. Then enter insert mode again (a).
7. Type </code>.
8. Return to normal mode (<esc>).
9. Then stop recording (q).

After you can repeat this command using @a or @@ for repeat last used command.
Dont forget to be positionned at the rigth place when you invoke a or you will not get the expected result.

Answer (score 2):

A couple other people have run into problems repeating things with surround.vim:

- [Repeating surround with “.” command in VIM](https://stackoverflow.com/q/497485/224354)
- [Vim Surround + Repeat, wraps my text with ^M](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4629090/224354)

In the first link, there is a quote from the surround.vim docs that implies visual mode surrounding doesn't work:

> The "." command will work with ds, cs,
>   and yss if you install repeat.vim

And given the text elements surrounding it, I don't think there's a way to surround just the #005462 without using visual mode.

**So for this particular problem,** I think a quick, repeatable search and replace is your best bet.

```
:s/: \(#......\);/: <code>\1<\/code>;/g
```

Go to the right line, and type or paste this in command-line mode and press enter.

Move to the next line and press `&` to repeat it.

If you know you want to replace ALL of them in the file, you can add `%` before the `s/` command, like so:

```
:%s/: \(#......\);/: <code>\1<\/code>;/g
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Check out [this Vimcasts.org](http://vimcasts.org/episodes/converting-haml-to-erb-with-vim-macros/) episode on converting haml to erb. You can use the same technique to accomplish your task.